# FullCalendar + cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, fullcalendar

I set [`jquery FullCalendar`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/) to get events from an action of `CakePhp`:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left:   'title',
                center: '',
                right:  'today agendaDay,agendaWeek,month prev,next'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            firstHour: 8,
            weekMode: 'variable',
            aspectRatio: 2,
            editable: true,
                  eventSources:{
                    url:'/mycontrollers/feed',
                    type:'POST',
                    error:function(data){console.log('errore feed!');
                    }
});
```

And the action in mycontrollers is:

```
public function feed()
    {  
        if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
        {
            $data = $tis->request->data;
            $res = array('title'=>'prova','start'=>'2014-03-19 21:00:00');
           return new CakeResponse(array('body'=>json_encode($res)));

        }

    }
```

When I load the page `fullcalendar` is, no events is shown and in the JS debug area I do not see ajax call to the action.
I am missing something?

**[EDIT]**

Now it works (I changed eventSources in events). Data event arrive back to the ajax but are not shown in the calendar...

**SOLUTION**

It was an error in the data array

```
$res[] = array('title'=>'prova','start'=>'2014-03-19 21:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this lets see

```
//in your controller
function feed(){
       ....
       ....
      //return json
      $this->set('events', json_encode($res));
}

//view
<script>
   var events = <?php echo $events; ?>
   var eventList = jQuery.parseJSON( events );


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2014-01-12',
    editable: true,
    events: eventList
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like that the problem is in eventSources: it should be events and not eventSource

Comment: I am just reading the doc of fullCalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/